# How to obtain a random string from a list

Tags: python, list, random

My class was recently introduced to lists and our task is to randomly obtain a name from the said list, This is the code i have generated

```
import random
Random1 = random.randint(0,7)
Class_List = ['Noah','Simone','Ji Ho','Thanh','Nathanial','Soo','Mickel','Tuan','Thuy Linh']
print (ClassList[{}].format(Random1))
```

However i receive this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mickel/Documents/Python/RPS Tournament/Rock Paper Sissor Tornament.py", line 4, in <module>
    print (ClassList[{}].format(Random1))
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict
```

Any solutions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows minimal effort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python has a very simple method for this: `random.choice`

```
import random

class_list = ['Noah','Simone','Ji Ho','Thanh','Nathanial','Soo','Mickel','Tuan','Thuy Linh']
print(random.choice(class_list))
```

Regarding why your answer isn't working:

```
print (ClassList[{}].format(Random1))
```

`.format` is for interpolating a value into a string  - for example`"{}".format(5)`. Obviously this is something different than what you're doing. If you wish to still use your approach, here's how:

```
Class_List = ['Noah','Simone','JiHo','Thanh','Nathanial','Soo','Mickel','Tuan','Thuy Linh']
Random1 = random.randint(0,len(Class_List))
print (ClassList[Random1])
```

Comment: I should be `random.randint(0, len(...) - 1)`. Randint "returns a random integer N such that `a <= N <= b`." I.e. including both the min and max values.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) for this.  Read the documentation I've linked.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing a value from the list in a form of an empty dictionary where an index number should be instead. That's why you get an error. But you spelled it wrong anyway. It should be "Class_List", not "ClassList".

As for your questing, personally I would do it this way

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random

Class_List = ['Noah','Simone','Ji Ho','Thanh','Nathanial','Soo','Mickel','Tuan','Thuy Linh']

random.shuffle(Class_List)

print (Class_List[0])
```